# How to list keys added to ssh-agent with ssh-add?

Tags: ssh, key-authentication, ssh-agent

How and where can I check what keys have been added with `ssh-add` to my `ssh-agent`?

Answer (score 522, accepted):

Use `ssh-add -l` to list them by fingerprint.

```
$ ssh-add -l
2048 72:...:eb /home/gert/.ssh/mykey (RSA)
```

Or `ssh-add -L` to get the full key in OpenSSH format.

```
$ ssh-add -L
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc[...]B63SQ== /home/gert/.ssh/id_rsa
```

The latter format is the same as you would put them in a `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

Comment: [rahul@srv1~]$ ssh-add -l
Could not open a connection to your authentication agent.

Comment: @RahulPatil Are you running an SSH agent on that machine? Run this on the same machine as to which you've added the keys, not the remote one!

Comment: You could run this command on the remote host if key agent forwarding is enabled.

Comment: Example: `ssh-agent sh -c 'ssh-add; ssh-add -l'`

Comment: @RahulPatil To run the ssh agent `eval \`ssh-agent -s\``. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17846529/could-not-open-a-connection-to-your-authentication-agent

Comment: I thought `ssh-agent` would have an option to perform this.

Comment: @Shiplu You're talking to the SSH agent with the use of `ssh-add`. Perhaps you're missing the point of that the `ssh-agent` instance is the *background task* with the key management, started at desktop session login time. Please refer to the manpage of `ssh-agent` for more thorough explanation.

Comment: @gertvdijk I was in fact talking about naming. From the name `ssh-add` it sounds like this command should only add keys to agent. And then `ssh-agent` should know what keys its holding. My perspective was different.

Comment: @kenorb I would post the command as an answer because the one liner is nice .

Answer (score 21):

Surprisingly the MacOS version of `ssh-add` at some point stopped showing the filename's as with the Linux variant. I wrote this script which does the same for fingerprints that have a corresponding file in `~/.ssh/`.

I call the function `ssh-add_wf`, wf = with file. The details on the function are below:

```
$ type ssh-add_wf
ssh-add_wf is a function
ssh-add_wf ()
{
    while read -r line; do
        for file in ~/.ssh/*.pub;
        do
            printf "%s %s\n" "$(ssh-keygen -lf "$file" | awk '{$1=""}1')" "$file";
        done | column -t | grep --color=auto "$line" || echo "$line";
    done < <(ssh-add -l | awk '{print $2}')
}
```

#### Example

```
$  ssh-add_wf
 SHA256:mwvSCr2CXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  myuser@mydom.lan  (RSA)  /Users/myuser/.ssh/ssh_myuser@mydom.lan_id_rsa.pub
 SHA256:qInIrnKcXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  myuser@mydom.com  (RSA)  /Users/myuser/.ssh/github_myuser@mydom.com_id_rsa.pub
 SHA256:tX+AAJA0XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 SHA256:EyNkhTLQXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  myuser@mydom.com  (RSA)  /Users/myuser/.ssh/ssh_myuser@mydom.com_id_rsa.pub
 SHA256:KKKVwtvFXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
 SHA256:tr0hZP52XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Above, any keys within `ssh-add`'s output that match to a file in `~/.ssh/` directory will include the file's name in the output in the 4th column. Any keys that do not will have that column empty. In this output we have 3 keys which have files that match.

#### Mechanics of function

The script uses 2 loops. The outside loop is a `while` which takes the output of `ssh-add`. This output is all the fingerprints of SSH keys loaded into `ssh-agent`.

The interior loop is a `for` loop which goes thru the contents of all the files matching this pattern, `~/.ssh/*.pub`. For each file we interrogate it with `ssh-keygen -lf <file>` and then drop the first column of this output:

*...before...*

> 4096 SHA256:mwvSCr2CXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  myuser@mydom.lan

*...after...*

> SHA256:mwvSCr2CXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX  myuser@mydom.lan

This string is then printed along with the name of the file:

> printf "%s %s\n" "$(ssh-keygen -lf "$file" | awk '{$1=""}1')" "$file"

At the end of the execution of this loop is the following:

> | column -t | grep "$line" || echo "$line"

This formats the output so that it's column formatted (`column -t`).

At this point we look at this output for the fingerprint from `ssh-add` via the `grep "$line"`. If a match is found we print our `printf` output, otherwise we fall back to just printing the original fingerprint from `ssh-add`, `$line`.

#### References

- [Checking ssh public key fingerprints](https://www.phcomp.co.uk/Tutorials/Unix-And-Linux/ssh-check-server-fingerprint.html)

Comment: What happened is that OpenSSH adopted a new private key storage format that has support for comments inside the private key, which of course can't be changed if you don't have the passphrase. If the private key is stored in this new file format (which you can recognize by the `BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY` at the top of the file) , then `ssh-add -l` displays it; if not, it instead displays the name of the file from which the key was loaded.